# document.onmouseup = null

Tags: javascript, функции, события, drag-n-drop, null

```
thumb.onmousedown = function(e) {

  ...

    document.onmouseup = function() {
        document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
      };

  ...

}
```

примерно так выглядит обработчик для Drag'n'Drop'а. Он работает.
Но мне не ясно то как работает присваивание "**document.onmouseup = null**", в функции обработчике на этом самом **document.onmouseup** ... По идее это должна быть одноразовая функция - присвоили null, он должен перечеркнуть саму эту функцию. Но так не происходит. Функция продолжает работать. Почему?

Answer (score 1):

`thumb.onmousedown`, `document.onmouseup` события вешаются на разные елементы, примерная логика такова :

зажали лкм на елементе, добавили документу ивентхэндлер для отслеживания координат `document.onmousemove`, ну чтобы знать куда мы передвигаем текущий елемент.

отпустили лкм - значит процесс Drag'n'Drop'а завершен, елемент оказывается на том месте, где отпустили лкм, а ивентхэндлеры на документе уже не нужны, поетому их удаляем (`document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;`).

При зажатии лкм уже на следующем елементе просто повторяем вышеописаные действия.